# How to join UV islands based on shape?

Tags: uv

I've got an object which I've segmented into sets of identical UV islands (using seams of course). I want to apply a custom texture, and to streamline the process and allow for a smaller texture image, I want to be able to apply the same UV island to multiple identical segments in the object.

I've tried this multiple ways but have had little success:

- Manually moving each vertex: The vertices aren't merged with each other, and selecting a single vertex will select multiple vertices in the UV if it runs along a seam.
- Magic UV add-on copy/paste UV: Doesn't preserve the relative locations of the vertices or seams, and doesn't actually join the vertices.
- Splicing vertices: Only seems to splice vertices based on the 3d model itself.
- Welding vertices: Selecting a single vertex will select multiple vertices in the UV if it runs along a seam.

I would prefer if I didn't have to split the object into multiple objects. Thanks.